# loadClip as2 not loading swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, moviecliploader

can anyone help me figure out why this will not load in my swf? I'm getting no errors.

```
var my_mcl:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();//Used to load the image

button1_mc.onPress = function()
{
my_mcl.loadClip(B.swf,container_mc);//loading a movie into a container movie clip (just an empty mc on the stage)
trace("a")
};

button2_mc.onPress = function()
{
my_mcl.loadClip(B.swf,container_mc);//loading a movie into a container movie clip (just an     empty mc on the stage)
    trace("b")
};

var mclListener:Object = new Object();
my_mcl.addListener(mclListener);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can see that is an issue in your code is that the URL to the SWF that you want to load should be encased in double quotes:

```
my_mcl.loadClip("B.swf", container_mc);
```